How to overlay root (/) of a running server with my set of directories?
I would appreciate if you could help me with the following problem.
I am developing a set of utilities with different configurations and thus I need to debug them. My own notebook serves as a base for different services like DNS, DHCP and stuff, so I can't reboot it quite often, preferably not at all.
My utilities are organized in a tree that mimics FHS and are packed into .tar.gz file. So it has /etc, /opt, /usr and stuff inside.
What I need is to mount the unpacked tar.gz file and unite it with existing root fs so it looked like I installed them. After my tests I need to unmount them without any traces.
I stumbled into several problems as I have chosen overlay fs as a base for my experiments with that task:

If I choose real root (/) tree as a lowerdir= for overlay fs, the system hangs - the problem is that lowerdir cannot be modified (but root fs is obviously does that quite often).
If I mount overlay for each of directories from my tar.gz - it works but still no luck with modifications, especially /etc and /var - I need to store data there and if I mount lowerdir=/var - I constantly get errors. Also and most annoying - I can't unmount overlay without 'Filesystem busy' error - that happens with /usr.
I tried a bunch of different approaches like symlinks for lowerdir (stupid but it did not work), different --bind mounts and stuff - no luck.

So I have these questions and would appreciate your help:

Is it really so hard to alter the lowerdir= in overlayfs? Are there any approaches? I just need to add files transparently to existing filesystem and then later remove them, storing all modifications into lowerdir. Is it really a severe problem for overlay fs?
Why does /usr fs always hangs and fails to unmount even though lsof shows no holding processes? I have no problem with /opt, /etc, even /bin unmounting it they were mounted as overlays, but /usr is always a problem and it 100% leads to reboot.
Are there any suggestions for a pretty simple problem: place a set of files into existing running file system, provide access and modifications possibilities and then remove all installed files? Of course, KVM is an answer, but I think that it is too much.

Thank you.

Keyword : chroot
And, You can try to put the service into Docker
There are many docker image files are ready
Google docker hub and search your service
mkdir -p /ProjectExam/test1
tar xvfz Package1.tgz /ProjectExam/test1
cd /ProjectExam/test1
chown -r root.root * .
 #... Make Sure Your Environment is complete !
 #... include /etc/passwd|group and /.../*.so, file's perm/owner ...etc.
netstat -anpt | grep ":80" 
 #... make sure there's no program is using the tcp port of my test program
sudo chroot /ProjectExam/test1  ./MyTestProgram 
 #... the path of `./MyTestProgram` is based on the root calculation that has been switched with `chroot` 

If there's some program is opening data/library file
It's NOT passible to override it online, but there's some tricky ...

rename(move to some other path) library file
replace new library into correct path and file name
restart your program/service as soon as you can
enjoy


That is a good suggestion, but what I need is exactly online overlaying (with or without overlayfs): I need to test my software as it is running together with my system, no chroot here is possible because it becomes chroot-ed system, then. So the problem here is how is it possible, if possible at all)

@Mirimat  Online is Impossible for some file already been locked by some program that is running !!  But you can reference the tricky part ... Hope it can solve your problem, but actually it should restart your service for replace file. Absolutely NOT online !!

Oh, I see. Ok, I will try to find out how to manage this. Thank you!
